# JSON object to php variables

Tags: php, javascript, json

I need to convert a JSON object that the php receive from the html form into php variable. I have two forms form1 gives the values and form2 submits them. this is where I give form2 the JSON string value

```
-html--javascript function-

var myObj = {
    "username" : theUsername,
    "name" : theName,
    "surname" : theSurName,
    "email" : theEmail,
    "password" : thePass,
    "confirmpass" : thePass2,
    "dob" : theDate,
    "gender" : theGender,
    "age" : theAge
};

var jsonstr=JSON.stringify(myObj);
document.forms["form2"]["hide"].value = jsonstr; //form2 gets the whole string
```

-php-
//$jstr = $_REQUEST["hide"];

//$newObj=JSON.parse(jstr);

//$name = $newObj.name;

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work

I used the post method in the html.
How do I now convert it back into seperate variables in php ?

Comment: Separate variables? Do you mean: $username, $name, $surname...?

Comment: It's probably a mere wording issue but JSON can never be an object: JSON is a *string*. That's why there is an `stringify()` method.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

The result of a json_decode is an associative array with the keys and values that were present in your javascript object.

If you don't know how to get the information after you've posted to a PHP script, take a look at the superglobal [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). If you're not familiar with that however, I suggest buying a PHP book or read trough some tutorials :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string index from de JSON send it to a php page

```
var myObj = {
    "username" : theUsername,
    "name" : theName,
    "surname" : theSurName,
    "email" : theEmail,
    "password" : thePass,
    "confirmpass" : thePass2,
    "dob" : theDate,
    "gender" : theGender,
    "age" : theAge 
}
```

Then in the PHP Page:

```
  extract($_POST);
```

Then you should see your variables $name, $surname, $email...

Source http://php.net/extract